# How do I update a subversion server from 1.5 to 1.6 on windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, svn, update

I need to update subversion to make it behave better with branching. how do I go about updateing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server) on Windows 2003 (as I am), all you have to do is run the new setup file.

Comment: VisualSVN is a nice clean easy solution for Windows server.